# Processing all elements in a BlockingQueue

Tags: java, blockingqueue

I am parsing an XML document, building an object from the information that I parse, and then putting that object into a blocking queue.

For testing purposes, the size of the blocking queue is 3 and I have 4 pages that I need to process.  What I'd like to happen is that after all possible objects have been added they should all be taken off.  I've tried using a while loop (as shown below) to take all the elements out of the queue but a there seems to be a null preventing it from going through the rest of the queue.

I'm new to threads in Java and I'm guessing that's where my trouble lies.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Runnable parser = new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            saxParser.parse("file_to_parse.xml", handler);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

Runnable takeOff = new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            while(handler.bq.peek() != null)
            {
                handler.bq.take();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

new Thread(parser).start();
new Thread(takeOff).start();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem is that `take` is going to block on an empty queue (`poll` is the method that returns null on an empty queue), so your loop won't terminate (unless `parser` is adding a null to the queue, which ought to be an error).  You're also calling `take` too often - the first `take` call (in the while loop's guard) is removing an element, and then the second `take` call (inside the while loop) is removing another element, which means that you're discarding half of the queue's elements.  Try something like this instead

```
try {
    String temp;
    while((temp = handler.bq.poll()) != null) {
        // process temp
    }
}
```

This will only work if you don't start `takeOff` until `parser` is finished adding items to the queue (when `offer` returns false) - otherwise `poll` might return null and terminate `takeOff` while `parser` is still adding items to the queue.  Here's an alternative that lets you run `parser` and `takeOff` at the same time

```
String temp;
try {
    while(true) {
        temp = handler.bq.take();
        // process temp
    }
catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    // ignore exception
}
while((temp = handler.bq.poll()) != null) {
    // process temp
}
```

Then you need to `interrupt()` the `takeOff` thread when `parser` is finished: this will exit the `while(true)` loop, after which the thread will go to the `while((temp = handler.bq.poll()) != null)` loop to finish removing items from the queue.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I should note that when I said `while(handler.bq.take() != null)` that was a mistake. It was supposed to be `peek()`; I've updated my original post. I will work with your suggestions and hopefully get something working.  Thanks again.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you use a `String temp` and what do you mean by `// process tmep`?

Comment: @joshft91 I was assuming that the blockingqueue held strings - if it holds something else e.g. `XMLDocuments` then this should be `XMLDocument temp;` `// process temp` means to do whatever it is you're supposed to be doing with `temp` - if all you're doing is removing items from the queue without processing them in any way, then this should be a nop. Also, `while(handler.bq.peek() != null)` has the same problem as `while(handler.bq.poll() != null)` in that it might prematurely terminate the thread.

Comment: Ah, alright.  Yeah, the blockingqueue is holding objects and all I'm doing with them right now is removing/discarding the objects.